# What is the best way to do ajax file uploads in Rails 3.x

Tags: ajax, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What is the best way to achieve ajax file uploads in Rails. I did alot of research, did some testing with remote forms and searched for some jquery plugins. All the plugins i found seemed outdated and i don't know which one will play nice with rails 3.x. Do you guys have any advice on this topic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you'll have to be browser specific at the moment.  The various browsers are implementing file APIs that allow javascript to read files from the machine.  Previously, there was no real way to achieve AJAX file uploading (I think it was for security reasons, but I'm not sure on all the details).  I've implemented drag/drop AJAX file uploading before; I can't remember the exact details, but here are some of the resources I used.  If I get a chance, I'll see if I can find my code and how I implemented it.

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php

http://www.skuunk.com/2011/04/reading-ajax-xhr-file-uploads-in.html

http://www.centurion-project.org/articles/html5-multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications (best - Mozilla docs)

The Mozilla docs are very useful and got me most of the way there.